# Facing this exception [java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError]

Tags: java, android, sugarorm

**java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError**

I searched for the issue and found the cause on [this thread](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/203)

It seems to be that some of the library have ***conflicting Rx java library***, I googled more on the libraries that I am using but no success.

**Here is the list of libraries in my app:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.0@jar'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.7.1'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile project(':zap_viewpager_indicator')
```

**Here is the log Cat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nash.zap.testing, PID: 15530
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
            at com.orm.SugarDb.getDomainClass(SugarDb.java:60)
            at com.orm.SugarDb.getDomainClasses(SugarDb.java:41)
            at com.orm.SugarDb.createDatabase(SugarDb.java:104)
            at com.orm.SugarDb.onCreate(SugarDb.java:100)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at com.orm.Database.getDB(Database.java:18)
            at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:205)
            at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:172)
            at com.nash.zap.database.UserTable.getThisUser(UserTable.java:53)
            at com.nash.zap.BaseApp.onCreate(BaseApp.java:69)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5115)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found
            at com.apigee.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.CoreXMLDeserializers.<clinit>(CoreXMLDeserializers.java:37)
                at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
                at com.orm.SugarDb.getDomainClass(SugarDb.java:60)
                at com.orm.SugarDb.getDomainClasses(SugarDb.java:41)
                at com.orm.SugarDb.createDatabase(SugarDb.java:104)
                at com.orm.SugarDb.onCreate(SugarDb.java:100)
                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                at com.orm.Database.getDB(Database.java:18)
                at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:205)
                at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:172)
                at com.nash.zap.database.UserTable.getThisUser(UserTable.java:53)
                at com.nash.zap.BaseApp.onCreate(BaseApp.java:69)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5115)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Please Help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you perhaps found a solution to this problem?